# Catastrophic Backtracking regular expression example in Java 9+

Tags: java, regex, java-9, backtracking

Does anyone have an example of a [catastrophic backtracking in a regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), which works in Java 11? Most of the usual examples (like "(a+a+)+b") are [fixed since java 9](https://andy.hammerhartes.de/regex-improvements-in-openjdk-9-less-exponential-backtracking.html). The best would be one without back-references, no idea if it's possible in JDK 9+.

In our application we have a logic to control such backtracking, and to test that logic we used the expression "(x+x+)+y". After upgrading to JDK 11 it no longer causes the need behavior.

Comment: I feel your question need more detail to explain your problem.

Comment: Added more context and info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running java 14 and the backtracking issue still exists.  It takes the following about 6 seconds to fail.

```
String regex = "(a+a+a+a+a+a+)+b";
String str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

This can be prevented by using independent group(s) `(?>X)`. Once the group matches the first time, the engine checks to see if the following matches the `b`. If it doesn't, no need to repeat as backtracking will not change that outcome.  So it fails instantly (even for larger expressions and/or test strings).

```
String regex1 = "(?>(a+a+a+a+a+a+)+)b";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex1));
```

Comment: Thanks, lengthening both the expression and the test string helped.

Comment: Of course, there’s the difference between six seconds and the “practically never returns” of Java 8…